# Adding microsoft repository in docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to install some azxure tools in a docker container and following the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v3%2Clinux%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash&view=form-recog-3.0.0

I setup my docker file as follows:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim AS build

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    gpg

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
RUN mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs)-prod $(lsb_release -cs) main" 
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/$(lsb_release -rs | cut -d'.' -f 1)/prod $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

RUN apt-get update
```

Now on the last `update` statement, I am getting the error:

```
> [ 7/11] RUN apt-get update:
#10 0.835 E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list (Component)
#10 0.835 E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I am also not sure how to debug this. I would like to see the output of the generated list file but am unable to echo it during the build process.

**EDIT**
What was needed was a change in the base image. Changing it to:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim-bullseye AS build
```

works. I think the older one was based on Alpine.

Comment: You can add debug-commands. Just put a `RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list` before the `RUN apt update` and debug your file.

Comment: np, can you post your fix as an answer?